# How to get keys and values from dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, key, key-value

I have my dictionary as per below

```
my_dict = {4: 8, 3: 11, 4: 10, 5: 10, 8: 5, 9: 5, 10: 10, 5: 2}
```

I am trying to figure out how to get a sorted list when `key == value` and also when iterating the value becomes the key. The result then is

> [[2,5,4,8],[10]]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on `also when itinerating the value becomes the key. `?

Comment: The example dictionary is not valid, because it contains two duplicated keys (i.e. `4` and `5`). Also, there is only one item where key == value (`10: 10`), so the expected result doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There cannot be duplicated keys in a dictionary, `my_dict` does not have all the key value pairs, use a list of tuples instead.

Comment: correct dictionary my_dict = {4: 8, 3: 11, 6: 10, 7: 10, 8: 5, 9: 5, 10: 10, 5: 2}.
I need to get this part [2,5,4,8]; this has been sorted inverted but without that, then it is [4,8,5,2] which is coming from keys : values {4:8, 8:5; 5:2} {10:10}

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
my_dict = {1: 3, 4: 2, 2: 6, 10: 10}

loop_backs = set()
new_dict = my_dict.copy()
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if k == v:
        loop_backs |= {k}
        del new_dict[k]
repeated = set(new_dict.values()).intersection(new_dict.keys()) | loop_backs
res = set()
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    if (k in repeated) or (v in repeated):
        res |= {k,v}
print(res, loop_backs)
```

> {2, 4, 6} {10}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200108/discussion-on-answer-by-yukashima-huksay-how-to-get-keys-and-values-from-diction).